Case sensitive on Nhibernate in Search Path Postgres
I trying use a string connection who have a Search Path and this one have a Schema who is Case sensitive. I already tried use " and ' but no of these helps me, anyone have see this?
Server=localhost;User Id=postgres;Password=senior123456789@;database=postgres;MaxPoolSize=100;SearchPath=TestBase;Port=5432;
